# Can I Switch Shells On Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

As far as I know; Ubuntu Touch uses bits and parts of Android's open implementation to handle the parts necessary to work on the Nexus 4 and other devices. I'm completely shooting in the dark; but how *probable* would it be for that operating system to run/use a separate desktop environment for the device.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the running unity desktop with:

```
adb shell
su - phablet
stop unity8
```

Now you can start up whatever you want, as long as it runs with Mir. Everything supporting Qt5 shouldn't be a problem at this point and other toolkits will be supported in the future.